# .htaccess Search Engine & User Friendly URL's

Tags: php, .htaccess

### Site Structure:

- SITE ROOT

  - /Desktop/ *- For everything seen at domain.com*
  - /Mobile/ *- For everything seen at m.domain.com*
  - /Admin/ *- For everything seen at admin.domain.com*

### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ $1.php?id=$2&name=$3
```

I've tried placing this at `SITE ROOT` and `/Desktop/`.

### The Problem

I've set up a testing page `domain.com/company.php` which simply has `<h1>Hello World</h1>` within.

Upon going to: http://domain.com/company.php?company_id=74&name=DesignSourceLtd

"Hello World" displays

Upon going to: http://domain.com/company/74/DesignSourceLtd

A 404 page shows.

### Question(s)

How do I make my URL search engine & user friendly and all preceding 'pages' of `company` show the `company.php` template?

Answer (score 2):

**Solution 1**

You can handle all the URIs within index.php by creating .htaccess file like this (So you can treat any parameter as you want and other benefits ) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond &{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

And access parameters with `explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])` and you can include company.php

**Solution 2**

You can create a spesific handle for company.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond &{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^company\/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)\/([-_a-zA-Z0-9]*)$ company.php?company_id=$1&name=$2[QSA,NC,L]
```

Solution 2 doesn't catch first url parameter because your GET Queries are spesific for company.php

Comment: I'm new to this method of not creating loads of pages and having PHP create them all for you via a database table. So if I wanted tutorials.php, forums.php, this.php and that.php all with different templates would I use the second solution creating multiple `RewriteRule`, if not, could you expand a little on the first solution please?

Comment: If you are going to use different templates you definitely shoud use the First Solution. Handling all the request within one page will give you a real flexible code. Anyway as you know we are exploding the URI with `explode('/'..` that means if i'm gonna load a file that file name is the first item of array that returned from explode function. So you can easily include that file and use the other exploded items as parameters for your pages.

Comment: Also you can check it out for an idea : https://github.com/klein/klein.php If you can't understand what to do i will gladly help about more.

Comment: Can you please explain `^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [QSA,NC,L]`, how does `index.php/$1` refer to the likes of `this.php` or `that.php`? Do I need an `index.php` somewhere or can I just upload the templates like `company.php`, `users.php` and whatnot?

Answer (score 1):

Your options should be `Options +FollowSymLinks` - not sure if that will affect the outcome, however. Your forward slashes should also be escaped. Try regex101.com to test.

See https://regex101.com/r/PQpiLt/1

Comment: Cleaner version: https://regex101.com/r/PQpiLt/2 

Something to keep in mind is that you may want to use a router, otherwise you'll have to write quite a few rewrites... for example, what if users wanted to go to "/company" or "/companies" to view a listings page?

Comment: Wow, that looks like a pretty advanced useful source link. I don't really understand it however I think I understand what you're saying. Like when I want forums.php and company.php and this.php?

Comment: This is where a framework like laravel comes in handy, it allows you to define routes and whatnot. You can use /company.php - doesn't matter, but it's not consistent with what you're doing to view a single company.